# test cases are executing before completing the beforeAll.?

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to run the testcase after completing the beforeAll hook.

But it is not working as expected, testcases are running before completing the beforeAll Hooks. How to resolve this issue.?

```
 describe('Testing : Protein superposition LOGIN', async () => {
    beforeAll(async function () {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 3500000;
        await browser.get(loginData.URL);
        await browser.refresh();
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        await page.funcLogin(loginData.VALID.USERNAME, loginData.VALID.PASSWORD);
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        expect(await userLoginStatus.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        console.log('LOGIN Status : Ok');

    });

    it('Check Login', async function () {

        try {
            var temp = await alerts.getPageHeaderName();
            console.log("Temp Detail", temp);
            // ...
            // ....
        } catch (e) {

            throw new Error(e);
        }

    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I experienced an issue similar to this one before and I used the `done` function provided by `Jasmine`.

```
// remove async on the describe callback because it is doing nothing I think
describe('Testing : Protein superposition LOGIN', /* async */ () => {
   // add done argument inside of the function parameter 
   beforeAll(async function (done) {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 3500000;
        await browser.get(loginData.URL);
        await browser.refresh();
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        await page.funcLogin(loginData.VALID.USERNAME, loginData.VALID.PASSWORD);
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        expect(await userLoginStatus.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        console.log('LOGIN Status : Ok');
        // call done to let jasmine know I am done with this block now
        done();
    });

    it('Check Login', async function () {

        try {
            var temp = await alerts.getPageHeaderName();
            console.log("Temp Detail", temp);
            // ...
            // ....
        } catch (e) {

            throw new Error(e);
        }

    })
});
```

Learn more about the done callback [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async).